When an electron jumps from higher to lower orbit, how does it not violate the law of conservation of mass?
I am just a higher secondary school student who was recently studying Bohr's model of the atom when this question popped into my mind. I know that when the electron jumps to lower orbits it releases photons and photons even though having neglibible mass, have some mass. Since the electrons mass isn't changed during the transition how is more mass being formed out of nowhere?

When a ball rolls down a hill where does the energy come from?

"even though having negligible mass, have some mass" Photons have strictly zero rest mass in modern physics. But we can produce massive particles in particle accelerators; there is no conservation of mass in modern physics, but conservation of energy and momentum approximately conserves mass along with Einstein's mass-energy-momentum relations.

Oh I didn't know this. Thank you!

If I may I shall interpret your question in terms of energy. This is because there is no law of conservation of rest mass, but there is a law of conservation of energy.
When an atom emits a photon the energy accounting goes as follows:
$$
E_e = E_g + h f
$$
where $E_e$ is the energy of the excited state of the atom, $E_g$ is the energy of the atom in its ground state (including any kinetic energy the atom may have if it is moving), and $h f$ is the energy of the emitted photon (given by Planck's constant multiplied by frequency).
The relevant physical concept here is to see that $E_e$ and $E_g$ refer to the whole atom, not just the electron. When the electron changes state within the atom, there is a change in the energy of interaction between electron and the rest of the atom (i.e. the other electrons and the nucleus). You can think of this as potential energy of the electron within the field provided by the rest of the atom, and there is a contribution from kinetic energy too.
To connect this to mass, let's treat the case where the atom starts at rest. In this case
$$
E_e = m_e c^2
$$
where $m_e$ is the rest mass of the atom in its excited state. Also
$$
E_g = m_g c^2 + E_r
$$
where $m_g$ is the rest mass of the atom in its ground state and
$E_r$ is the kinetic energy of the atom which is now moving because it recoils from the photon, thus conserving momentum. (This kinetic energy is called recoil energy). You can note that $m_e \ne m_g$ which is an example of the fact that rest mass is not conserved.

Great answer. It may be worth mentioning that $E_r$ (the recoil kinetic energy of the atom) is much smaller than $hf$ (the energy of the photon).
That's why many text books neglect $E_r$ altogether.

Thank you sir! I was so confused just because none of my books mentioned this recoil kinetic energy of the atom and it's the first time I'm hearing about this.

This answer will probably just confuse the OP. His question was in the context of the Bohr model, which is a classical (non-relativistic) model and thus does not know any relativistic mass/energy. Bohr assumed classical electromagnetic waves interacting with the atom, not massive photons (see e.g. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-9107-0_5 ). In Bohr's model all masses are exactly preserved and the potential energy of the photon just transformed into classical electromagnetic energy (which is massless).

Photons have a (rest) mass that is exactly zero, simply because they can't be at rest. You can assign a relativistic mass to them, but that corresponds to nothing else than the energy between the two atomic levels (as per $E=mc^2$). So there is no violation of mass conservation involved here.
